# How to find the difference between each element of two list while one of them is not a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, topology

I'm trying to write an algorithtm that finds the difference between 2 lists, but one of them is not a nested list.

For example;

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,[2,3],[3,4]]
```

Expected output is

```
expected = [[2,3,4],[1,4],[1,2]]
```

So the goal is, find `a-b1` where `b1` is the each element in `b` one by one.

I tried to convert them to `set()`,`frozenset()` used `filter()` etc. but none of them was succesful. Either I got integer error or an output that is wrong(in my case).

My actual goal is writing this algorithm for Topology, where `a` is the set and `b` is the Topology on `a`. So I'm trying to write the **closed set** of that Topology.

In the real question, `a` and `b` are both sets where `b` is a nested `set`, but I realized working with `lists` is easier than `sets` to achieve my goal, but still none of the answers similar to my question(on stackoverflow) were not successful.

How can I find the `closed set` of a `given set`, or, find the difference of all elements in the list2 from list1, where list2 is a nested list and list1 is not.

Answer (score 2):

When working with mathematical sets you should really use the provided `set` type in Python. I wrote your sets as Python sets:

```
a = {1,2,3,4}
b = [{1},{2,3},{3,4}]
```

Notice, that `b` is a list of sets; your topology on `a`. You can find differences between sets with the `-` operator (with two sets `A` and `B`, `A-B` is the same as the mathematical `A\B`):

```
res = [a-el for el in b]
```

Output:

```
In [11]: res
Out[11]: [{2, 3, 4}, {1, 4}, {1, 2}]
```

this is a list of the differences between the sets

**EDIT** Here is a way to transform your inputs in the way that you wanted:

First of all, prompt the user to write every set in parenthesis, to have a regular syntax, like for example: `(1),(1,2),(2,3,4)`

Now we need a regular expression to find the sets in the resulting string `"(1),(1,2),(2,3,4)"`:

```
import re
inp_list = re.findall(r"(?:\(([\d,]+))", inp_string)
```

Now we can start with the solution mentioned above:

```
res = [{int(number) for number in inp.split(",")} for inp in inp_list]
```

To understand the regex, [click here](https://regex101.com/r/sYMjIs/1)

Comment: note that "differences between sets" isn't symmetrical. `a-b != b-a`. +1 for changing OP inputs for `set`s, as they should be right from the start

Comment: The problem is I can't take each element of `b` as a set, for example if I do `set(input("input the elements"))` it takes "," as like an element. If I convert it to `int` I got an error. So when the user input the elements of `b` I can't convert them to a set, that's why I've used lists.

Comment: The input the user gives is `1,4,3` for example?

Comment: @user8408080 well, for example; `1,(1,2),(2,3,4)` as like in a Topology, usually its more than 1 element. So for example set(1) throws an integer error, while `2,3` doesn't give any error but takes "," as an element (comma).

Comment: @GLHF I think this should now fit your needs, but for a logical input the user should also put a set of length 1 in brackets

Answer (score 1):

with your inputs:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,[2,3],[3,4]]
```

now I'm converting `a` as a `set`

```
a = set(a)
```

then I'm performing set difference between `a` and elements of `b`, with just a test to see if the element is a simple value or a list. Convert back each element to `list` or use `sorted` to get increasing order.

```
result = [list(a-(set(be if isinstance(be,list) else [be]))) for be in b]
```

result:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [1, 4], [1, 2]]
```

Small variant, creating directly a `set` when passed a non-list:

```
result = [list(a-(set(be) if isinstance(be,list) else {be})) for be in b]
```

And non comprehension implementation

```
a = set(a)
result = []
for be in b:
    if isinstance(be,list):
        result.append(list(a-set(be)))
    else:
        result.append(list(a - {be}))
```

Only works with "flat" lists like your example

Comment: This works as you said,`a` is always a flat list. Could you write `result` as not in list comprehension form? I need to understand how this works, and this `result` is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [frozenset's or sets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset):

```
a = {1,2,3,4}    # normal set (mutable)
b = [1,frozenset({2,3}),frozenset({3,4})] # frozenset in list to keep ordering 

c = [ (a-x) if isinstance(x,set) else (a-set([x])) for x in b]

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[set([2, 3, 4]), set([1, 4]), set([1, 2])]
```

---

Unrolled list comp:

```
d = []
for top in b:
    d.append( a-top if isinstance(top,set) else a-set([top]) )

# d == c
```

`a-top` is just the shorthand for [set.difference](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference). Here is a [table of shorthands for sets (2.7 - still valid)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects).

Answer (score 0):

I consider to write a custom method which returns the difference between two list:

```
def difference(w, z):
  [w.remove(x) for x in z if x in w]
  return w
```

Then use the method in a for loop:

```
res = []
for y in b:
  tmp = a[:]
  if not isinstance(y, list): y = [y]
  res.append(difference(tmp, y))

print(res)
#=> [[2, 3, 4], [1, 4], [1, 2]]
```

---

I don't know if it is useful but in this case:

```
a = [1,2,2,3,4]
b = [1,[2,3],[3,4],5]
```

The result is `[[2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]]`

You can customize the method to better fit your needs.